# how to merge two and more array of objects in one with unique keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need create one array based on two and more another arrays with unique keys each elements in array
name of keys should be incremented
This data is for plotting by Recharts
but code below is incorrect, i got same value for each key

you can see demo https://jsfiddle.net/shuts13/hn52vpxf/

i have array of arrays:

```
const setOfArrays = [
[
{
     'dateTime': 1531612800000,
     'value': 97.0,
     'rangeMin': 79.0,
     'rangeMax': 110.0
},
{
     'dateTime': 1531512800000,
     'value': 96.0,
     'rangeMin': 79.0,
     'rangeMax': 110.0
}],
[{

      'dateTime': 1544745600000,
      'value': 82.7,
      'goal': 77.0

},{

      'dateTime': 1544745600000,
      'value': 81,
      'goal': 77.0

}],
[{
     'dateTime': 1531612800000,
     'value': 66.0,
     'rangeMin': 50.0,
     'rangeMax': 80.0
},{
     'dateTime': 1531612800000,
     'value': 65.0,
     'rangeMin': 50.0,
     'rangeMax': 80.0
}]
]
```

what i expected get on output

```
[
{
     'dateTime': 1531612800000,
     'value': 97.0,
     'rangeMin': 79.0,
     'rangeMax': 110.0,

     'dateTime1': 1544745600000,
     'value1': 82.7,
     'goal1': 77.0,

     'dateTime2': 1531612800000,
     'value2': 66.0,
     'rangeMin2': 50.0,
     'rangeMax2': 80.0

},
{
     'dateTime': 1531512800000,
     'value': 96.0,
     'rangeMin': 79.0,
     'rangeMax': 110.0,

      'dateTime1': 1544745600000,
      'value1': 81,
      'goal1': 77.0,

     'dateTime2': 1531612800000,
     'value2': 65.0,
     'rangeMin2': 50.0,
     'rangeMax2': 80.0
}
]
```

code what i had written is incorrect , value is duplicated, i dont know what is wrong

Comment: Your code should be in your question, and should be condensed from what you have on that fiddle

Comment: Should the output of merging `[{a: 1}, {a: 2}]` be `[{a: [1,2]}]` instead of `[{a:1, a2:2}]`? That would be a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) & [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

- Idea is to create an object with **key** as nested array `index` and **value** as the `object` as in the resulting array. And then use `Object.values` to get the result array.
- So to create object from the given array, we will use `Array.reduce` where for each item in array we will perform following action
- Iterate over the item objects array and check whether there exist an object in the reduced object for given index
- If there is no entry found, add the entry in the object with value as object `{...o}`
- Else if there is entry found, then for each key, value in the item object, update the corresponding object

**Note** - As the resulting object should be the length of the nested array, we know that number of keys in resulting object will be same as length of either of nested array. That is why in `a[i]`, `i` is the index of nested array. For the values, we know that first object in first array will come as it is and others will be suffixed with array index `j`. So, we have checked for the presence of object corresponding to an `index` in `a`, because for the first array objects, it will always be undefined and hence, we will be adding the key:value in resulting object. For others, we just need to loop and suffix with parent iterator `j` like `${k}${j}`

```js
const setOfArrays = [[{'dateTime':1531612800000,'value':97.0,'rangeMin':79.0,'rangeMax':110.0},{'dateTime':1531512800000,'value':96.0,'rangeMin':79.0,'rangeMax':110.0}],[{'dateTime':1544745600000,'value':82.7,'goal':77.0},{'dateTime':1544745600000,'value':81,'goal':77.0}],[{'dateTime':1531612800000,'value':66.0,'rangeMin':50.0,'rangeMax':80.0},{'dateTime':1531612800000,'value':65.0,'rangeMin':50.0,'rangeMax':80.0}]];

const result = Object.values(setOfArrays.reduce((a,c,j) => {
  c.forEach((o,i) => {
    if(a[i]) Object.entries(o).forEach(([k,v]) => Object.assign(a[i], {[`${k}${j}`] : v}));
    else a[i] = {...o};
  });
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice

Comment: I'm trying to figure out when do you decide that a new object is needed. I guess I don't understand what the OP is asking, it feels like the output would be a single object with bunch of properties, I must be missing something

Comment: @JuanMendes they are trying to merge the each index from all the inner arrays to one object

Comment: @adiga But the output is two objects?

Comment: @JuanMendes because each inner array has 2 objects.

Comment: The OP's array is made up of three arrays... isn't it? Mmm... I see, you merge the same index object from each of the inner arrays... Thanks guys. I guess what would clarify it for me is that the output should be as many objects as the list with the most objects?

Comment: Yes. So OP has an array of 3 arrays each of length 2 and wants to convert into an array with length 2 where wants to merge object at each index of all 3 arrays into 1

Comment: @JuanMendes tbh, I'm just guessing from the expected output. I'm not sure what OP means by "*unique keys each elements in array name of keys*". I thought they want to merge based on `dateTime` or something. But, it looks like merging `m x n` matrix to an array of `n` objects.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal one more questions, but if we will have arrays with different length: [[10][8][13]], can we paralel value set to null?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal here we have [[array.length =4], [3][2]]
i mean: 
```[
{
a: 1,
a1: 434,
a2: 342:
}, 
{
a: 14,
a1: 4434,
a2: 3442:
}, 
{
a: 1234,
a1: 4374,
a2: null:
},
{
a: 157,
a1: null,
a2: null:
}
]```
how we can set to `null`?

Comment: @shuts13 - Will the first array be the longest array?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal it does not metter, because we can sort array by length `setOfArrays.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);` - here first element is the longest

Comment: Okay. In the original array in the question, let us say 3rd array has only 1 object. Then how will you define which keys should be there for the missing object. The reason I am asking this is because the keys are not same across all the objects in all arrays.

Comment: Basically, I want you to provide some illustrations some where

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal we can set previous key,  i suppose on each iteration we should check if current keys is existed else we set previous keys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193549/discussion-between-nikhil-aggarwal-and-shuts13).

Answer (score 2):

From your output, you are merging the `m x n` matrix to an array of `n` items (column-wise)

So,

- `map` over the one of the inner arrays.
- Inside, `map` over `setOfArrays`
- Get an array of entries for the current column from each row using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) to flatten the arrays returned to one array.
- Add a suffix to each key when the *row* number of the matrix item is non zero.
- Create an object from the merged entries using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const setOfArrays = [[{'dateTime':1531612800000,'value':97.0,'rangeMin':79.0,'rangeMax':110.0},{'dateTime':1531512800000,'value':96.0,'rangeMin':79.0,'rangeMax':110.0}],[{'dateTime':1544745600000,'value':82.7,'goal':77.0},{'dateTime':1544745600000,'value':81,'goal':77.0}],[{'dateTime':1531612800000,'value':66.0,'rangeMin':50.0,'rangeMax':80.0},{'dateTime':1531612800000,'value':65.0,'rangeMin':50.0,'rangeMax':80.0}]];

const output = setOfArrays[0].map((obj, i) => {
  const entries = setOfArrays.flatMap((arr, j) => {
      const suffix = j || ''; // add index suffix for nonzero j
      return Object.entries(arr[i]).map(([k, v]) => [k+suffix, v]);
  })
  return Object.fromEntries(entries)
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Ha... This answer makes sense, and really elegant. @shuts13 This looks like what you were looking for.